# ASP.NET HttpContext is null on Azure

Tags: asp.net, blazor-server-side, httpcontext

I have a ASP.NET Blazor Web App, which is hosted on Azure. Everything works, except one minor thing. I use the `IHttpContextAccessor.HttpContext` as described in the [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

```cs
    public class SessionService : ISessionService
    {
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor;
        private readonly IUserService userService;

        public SessionService(
            IUserService userService,
            IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            this.userService = userService;
            this.httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        }

        public async Task<User> GetUser()
        {
            var userId = this.httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.Items["userId"]?.ToString();
            
            if (userId == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            if (!int.TryParse(userId, out var parsedUserId))
            {
                return null;
            }

            return await this.userService.Get(parsedUserId);
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public async Task AuthenticateUser()
        {
            if (this.httpContextAccessor.HttpContext == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            // Authentication Logic
            // ...

            this.httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Items["userId"] = authenticatedUser.id;
        }
    }
```

I later call this code similar to this:

```cs
var user = await sessionService.GetUser();
if (user == null)
{
   await sessionService.AuthenticateUser();
   user = await sessionService.GetUser();
}
```

This works on every local machine I've tested so far. It does not matter if I build it in Release or Debug. All of the data gets loaded correctly and I can retrieve the ID of the currently logged in user.

Anyways, if I publish the application to azure, the HttpContext is always null. I have checked the documentation multiple times now and cannot find anything that pushes me in the right direction. Do I need to configure something to specifically use the HttpContext?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to inject `AuthenticationStateProvider` to get info from graph and please don't use `IHttpContextAccessor` *because it has a security issue*, you can read more about that in [microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-6.0). 
 **How you can use `AuthenticationStateProvider`**: 
In  blazor page inject `AuthenticationStateProvider` like this:

```
[Inject]
public AuthenticationStateProvider AuthenticationState { get; set; }
 
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
  var AuthSate = await AuthenticationState.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
  var user = AuthSate.User;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I think I overcomplicated it for myself. I was already using the AuthenticationState to fetch the identity name of the currently logged in user. For some weird reason I thought it might be a good idea, to store exactly this data in a cookie. Anyways, as I just realized, when I read your answer, this does not make any sense whatsoever, since I can literally just directly access the AuthenticationState.